# Updating displayed values using inputfields (forms)

Tags: php, symfony

I want to update an user entity (selected with the unique userid).

It should look like a table (width = 3 fields), on the left you have the columnnames (first name, last name, etc), middle are the current values and on the right are input fields to for the new values.

Thats the current table made with divs in my edit.html.twig:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <span>Current</span>
        <span>Edit here</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Emailadress:</span>
        <span>{{ userById.getEmail }}</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>First name:</span>
        <span>{{ userById.getFirstname }}</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Last name:</span>
        <span>{{ userById.getLastname }}</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now comes the problem. Inside the last spans, I want input fields to edit the values. I tried to use a form that fills entities with values and combine it with name-fields and current-fields.

I tried to insert some Editfields into the Controllerfunction below, didnt get it to work :(

Currently Iam selecting the userid and building a form with it, passing the values to my edit view.

Only the inputfields are missing, displaying the current data works fine. Below is my editfunction:

```
public function editUserAction($id, Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userId = $em->getRepository('CompanyUserBundle:User')->find($request->get('id'));


    $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm($request->getSession()), new User(), array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('backend_user_management_edit', array('id' => $userId->getId())),
            'em' => $em)
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    $userData = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('CompanyUserBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($userId);

    if (!$userData) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No user found for id '.$userId
        );
    }

    return $this->render(
        'CompanyUserBundle:User:edit.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('backend_user_management_edit', array('id' => $userId->getId())),
            'userById' => $userId
        )
    );
}
```

How can I add Inputfields to edit the values and update the current user with the new values?

With kind regards

Comment: [Read the docs...](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Comment: Off topic: you load the user twice (`find()` and `findOneById()`). You should replace `$request->get('id')` by `$id` since `$id` is an argument of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function editUserAction($id, Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userId = $request->get('id');
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('CompanyUserBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($userId);

    if (!$userData) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No user found for id '.$userId;
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm($request->getSession()), $user, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('backend_user_management_edit', array('id' => $userId->getId())),
            'em' => $em)
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render(
        'CompanyUserBundle:User:edit.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('backend_user_management_edit', array('id' => $userId->getId())),
            'userId' => $userId,
            'user' => $user
        )
    );
}
```

View

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div>
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <span>Current</span>
        <span>Edit here</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Emailadress:</span>
        <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
        <span>{{ form.email }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>First name:</span>
        <span>{{ user.firstname }}</span>
        <span>{{ form.firstname }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Last name:</span>
        <span>{{ user.getLastname }}</span>
        <span>{{ form.lastname }}</span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Something like that, I haven´t tested it.

Comment: thank you for your work, i got some errors on it but ill try to fix it, more about it tomorrow